# JavaScript - SweetAlert clicking on text and removing it from there?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

There's addon called "SweetAlert". My question is if I show text there example, then can I add there code, if you click on that "text" then it removes it?

To create an alert in SweetAlert, you have to do something like that:

```
swal({
    title: "Items you want to purchase: ",
    text: itemcurt,
    type: "question",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, correct!',
    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
```

So there is that `text`. At the moment I got in there variable `itemcurt` which gets div and puts that div content there, but I would like to it will get that div content and some additional code, can I example make function and call it same way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you mean, your question isn't clear.  But you can always do something like this with jQuery:

```
<p id='my-text'>My Text</p>
```

And in your JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#my-text', function() {
         $(this).remove();
    }
}
```

This will remove the "p" tag with the "my-text" id from the DOM.  I am not sure what your code looks like, but if you're placing the example "

" tag back in the alert box every time, be sure to use the above listener style.

Comment: @JacobSeen  Can you update your post with the full code?  I don't have any idea what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Hello, I've made better thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941657/can-you-use-that-system-in-sweetalert